# Cannot visualize Google Maps on Android Emulator using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, android-emulator

I am developing an Android/ios application using flutter.

Flutter doctor

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.1 on channel stable at C:\SW\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7f20e5d18c (9 days ago), 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
    • Engine revision 22b600f240
    • Dart version 3.2.1
    • DevTools version 2.28.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\carlo.benussi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 15.9.58)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer
    • Visual Studio Team Explorer 2017 version 15.9.34118.181
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.0
    X Visual Studio 2019 or later is required.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\carlo.benussi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.78.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)       • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693]
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.200
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.97

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I am trying to test my application on an Android Emulator (Pixel 7 Pro API 30, Android 11).

When I switch to the map_page.dart (snippet)

```
child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          drawer: const ChocoTurDrawer(),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                initialCameraPosition: (_cameraPosition != null)
                    ? _cameraPosition!
                    : const CameraPosition(
                        target: Coordinates.turinCenter,
                        zoom: 14.4746,
                      ),
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                compassEnabled: true,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
                onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
                  _cameraPosition = position;
                },
                markers: _markers,
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 15,
                bottom: 85,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const FaIcon(Icons.tour_outlined),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Coordinates.getUserPosition().then((value) async {
                LatLng latLngValue = LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
                _updateUserLocationMarker(latLngValue);
                _moveCameraToCoordinates(latLngValue);
              }).onError((error, stackTrace) async {
                LoggerInstance.logger.e("Error getting user position.");
              });
            },
            child: const FaIcon(Icons.my_location_rounded),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I cannot visualize the map, it remains blank:
[image]

From the logs I can see some errors but they did not lead me to any solution:

```
W/ample.*******( 5200): Unsupported class loader
I/Google Maps Android API( 5200): Google Play services client version: 18020000
D/MapsInitializer( 5200): loadedRenderer: LEGACY
D/zzcc    ( 5200): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API( 5200): Google Play services package version: 201817022
I/TetheringManager( 5200): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.choco_tur
I/PlatformViewsController( 5200): Using hybrid composition for platform view: 0
D/EGL_emulation( 5200): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafe0300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xeb31ce90) (first time)
W/Gralloc4( 5200): allocator 3.x is not supported
E/EGL_emulation( 5200): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation( 5200): tid 5200: eglQueryContext(2019): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
D/HostConnection( 5200): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeafe7370, tid 5335
D/HostConnection( 5200): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation( 5200): eglCreateContext: 0xeafc93f0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
2
D/EGL_emulation( 5200): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafc93f0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xce641990) (first time)
W/DynamiteModule( 5200): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 5200): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
I/DynamiteModule( 5200): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
2
W/ample.******( 5200): Unsupported class loader
```

Note that I already checked that the OS used on the emulator supports google play services, and my Google Maps API_KEY was added to the Manifest like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:label="choco_tur"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@secrets/google_maps_api_key"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Seems that as well the Google Maps app on the emulator remains blank, so it is possible that the emulator has a general issue with loading maps. (NOTE: internet connection seems to be ok from the emulator)

EDIT: I have tried to workaround by using other emulated devices where I can see Google Maps app working fine, but still getting the same issue. My google maps API_KEY was correctly generated and has the right SDKs enabled (I also tried to regenerate a new API_KEY but with no luck). The only thing that I have in mind is that I operate behind a company VPN (that I cannot switch off) that might block the connection, but internet seems to be working fine on the emulated Android.

Comment: Check if your metadata is in between </activity> and </application> on the android manifest. Then flutter clean / flutter pub get and try again. If it doesn't work try to test in another emulador also.

Comment: Edited the question. I tried with other emulators (both x86_64 and x86) but always with the same issue

Comment: Okay, have you followed https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#getting-started ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383205/google-map-in-flutter-app-is-not-showing-up It may help you

Comment: I followed the guide but with the same result. I will check later today if I can make it work without VPN

Comment: If you have tried cloning a fresh sample of Google Maps for Flutter and still encounter the same issue, it is indeed possible that the issue is with your network.